# Fill letter with different color in certain direction

Tags: flutter, animation, draw

I need to create such animation in Flutter, in which by clicking on the letter(it can be svg, or ttf) it will fill with color in specific direction.
So, for example:
[image]

By clicking in letter, it should somehow be filled with color(let's say red), staring from top to bottom.
How it possible to do programmatically?

Comment: use [ShaderMask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sUL66pTQ7Q&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the package: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit.

It provides Colorize and LiquidTextFill which can be used to achieve what you need.